# How to unistall wordpress in wamp server in local host?

Tags: wordpress, wamp

Could anyone please explain how to unistall wordpress in wamp server. Also please explain how to transfer my live wordpress website files & database into wamp server localhost without any third party software?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply delete your WordPress folder from WAMP server. And to transfer your live WordPress website files & database into WAMP server, you can use "All-in-One WP Migration" plugin.

Answer (score 0):

For transferring the remote data you dont need to uninstall the wordpress. You just install the WP Clone Plugin at your remote and local wordpress installation. Now take a clone from Remote and Import it in Local using that WP Clone Plugin. That will do everything for you. Just remind that the admin username may change at local, you need to logged in using the remote admin username and password and later you can change it.

WP Clone : https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-clone-by-wp-academy/